# How to get post data from bootstrap 4 dropdown

Tags: express, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue.with dropdowns in bootstrap 4, using the button style dropdown with anchors. The dropdown functionality works fine, but when I actually submit the form, I'm not getting the values from the dropdowns. is there a special attribute or something besides name that I need to provide? I don't see the values in the request body in expressjs.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-5">
        <label for="sec_questions">
            Security Questions <span class="error_required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
              id="sec_questions" name="sec_questions" value="this" 
              role="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" 
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Please Select
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sec_questions">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    What is your mother's maiden name?
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    What is your pet's name?
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    What street did you grow up on?
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Where did you go in elementary school?
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Who was your first employer?
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every other field is present in the req body but dropdowns which is weird.

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap4` dropdown is there for styles. It's not a HTML form element. Unless you're using `javascript` to grab all the input values and submit them as a whole using `AJAX`, it won't automatically bind to your form.

To bind the selected data to your form submit, use `<select />` instead.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="sec_questions">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
        <option>What is your pet's name?</option>
        <option>What street did you grow up on?</option>
        <option>Where did you go in elementary school?</option>
        <option>Who was your first employer?</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/aq9Laaew/290563/

Don't forget the `name` attribute on the form element!